# Number of pairs with given OR value

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

Is it possible to write a function that takes an array of *n* integers and an integer *k* and returns the number of pairs of array elements with BITWISE OR value equal to *k* in better than O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) time?

Example: If we have an array = [21, 10, 29, 8] and k = 31, then the function should return 2, since the valid pairs are (21, 10) and (10, 29).

*** for clarity ***
 21 OR 10 = 31 , 21 OR 29 = 29 , 21 OR 8 = 29, 10 OR 29 = 31, 10 OR 8 = 10,29 OR 8 = 29, so answer is 2.

**** k is a constant which is always 31 .****

Comment: Can you provide an example

Comment: let array = [21, 10, 29 ,8] and k=31 ,  then the answer will be 2, the valid pairs are (21,10) and (10,29).

Comment: Using XOR? 21 = 10101 and 10 is 01010, so doing (21 XOR 10) == 31 should work. I'm not sure what language you're going to write this in but it will check for only one bit in each space.

Comment: @GeeTransit: The question states “BITWISE OR”.

Comment: Ohh, well that was my guess to how they wanted to get the elements. Still not sure how it gets the pairs. EDIT: Nvm, I've reread the question...

Comment: @GeeTransit , let I have a pair (31,31) in the array , the XOR would return 0 and will not include the pair(as i  need 31) .

Comment: You should clarify the question regarding how k is to be considered as affecting the time. As the answer I posted shows, the job can be done in O(n+k^2) time. If k is regarded as a constant, this is O(n). If k is not a constant, there may be faster solutions than O(n+k^2).

Comment: @EricPostpischil, uh , in my case actually the k is a constant , whose value is 2^(number  of bits in the binary representation of the maximum element of given array ) -1 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the units of time are elementary operations on a word size that spans *k*, then O(*n* + *k*<sup>2</sup>) is possible:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NumberOf(a) (sizeof (a) / sizeof *(a))


static unsigned Count(size_t N, unsigned *A, unsigned k)
{
    //  Count number of elements with each pattern of bits in k.
    unsigned *C = calloc(k + 1, sizeof *C);
    if (!C) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    for (size_t n = 0; n < N; ++n)
        if ((A[n] & ~k) == 0) ++C[A[n]];

    //  Count number of solutions formed with different values.
    unsigned T = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < k; ++i)
    for (size_t j = i+1; j <= k; ++j)
        if ((i | j) == k)
            T += C[i] * C[j];

    //  Add solutions formed by same value (only possible when both are k).
    T += C[k] * (C[k]-1) / 2;

    free(C);

    return T;
}


int main(void)
{
    unsigned A[] = { 21, 10, 29, 8 };
    printf("%u\n", Count(NumberOf(A), A, 31));
}
```

This can be reduced to O(*n* + *p*<sup>2</sup>), where *p* is the number of bits set in *k*, by compressing each array element to just those bits (removing bits not in *k* and shifting the remaining bits to be contiguous). Also, the main loop that counts the combinations could be improved, but I do not think that affects the O() time.

Comment: Nice solution sir , Big Fan :)

Comment: might be worth adding a check for `C[i] == 0` before the `for` `j` loop?

Answer (score 1):

People believe that the answer is "NO".

Assume that your `k` is `2^s - 1` (so it's `111...111` in binary) and all numbers are of at most `k`. Then

```
a or b = k <=> (~a) and (~b) = 0.
```

, where `~` is a "bitwise not". E.g.

```
110 or 101 = 111 <=> 001 and 010 = 0
```

This is a general Orthogonal Vector Problem (OVP), and popular conjecture states that it's not solvable faster than `O(n^2)` (there are some details I omit).

See Conjecture 1 here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.02824.pdf.

Comment: No brother ,Eric Postpischil solution is great and amazingly faster than 0(n^2) .

Comment: How did you test it? For `k = (1 << 31) - 1` it takes forever.

Comment: @AdityaRoshan: This answer and mine differ because they answer different questions, based on whether k is taken to be constant or not.

Comment: k is not that huge , it's just 31 . And i tested it for array of size 10^5 , random generated elements both by 0(n^2) (mine solution ) and 0(n+k^2) (Eric solution ) , and found a huge difference in running time.

Comment: @AdityaRoshan, in the future, you should state in the question that you are interested only in `k = 31`.

Comment: @ReputationFarmer Will do sir, thankyou for your time sir , and sorry , i'm new here.

Comment: @AdityaRoshan, it's OK. You are actually the only one who may suffer. If Eric didn't assume that `k` is a constant (and it's unclear to me why he did), you would have only my answer and wouldn't have you problem solved.